# Generic DAO disadvantages?

Tags: java, design-patterns, dao

I want to create a DAO layer for my application. After some  googling I found that many peoples uses Generic DAO approach ([Don't repeat the DAO!](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-genericdao/index.html)).

But I did not like this approach.

What if I need slightly different interfaces between DAO for different DAO implementations? (i.e. methods in generic interface not exactly same which I want to create in my DAO implementations)

What if my entity's primary key consists of more than one attribute?

Comment: By definition of word 'primary'.  There can be only ONE 'primary' key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need a slightly different DAO for a particular entity, you can always extend a generic one(`MySpecificDAO <....> extends GenericDAO<....>)`. Primary key can be composite itself, but it's impossible to have 2 primary keys .

Answer (score 2):

Straight from the article you linked to:

> Extending GenericDAO
>
> The interface for each DAO is, of course, based on the GenericDao interface. I just need to adapt the interface to a specific domain class and extend it to include my finder methods. In Listing 6, you can see an example of the GenericDao interface extended for a specific purpose

Regarding your last question: by definition, an entity has one and only one primary key.

Answer (score 2):

Disadvantage: you still have to implement the DAO. Stop following advice from 6 years ago, and use [Spring Data repositories](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories) instead. Then you don't have to write any implementations at all.

Answer (score 1):

> What if I need slightly different interfaces between DAO for different
>   DAO implementations?

you can override the method in your `GenericDaoImpl` class. or create a new method.

> What if my entity have 2 or more primary keys?

I guess you meant compound-key scenario. Note that usually the findOne/readOne/getOne method in `GenericDao` would expect a parameter, `(T key)` the T here is type, it could be composite primary key.

for example:

```
class PersonPK{
 private String name;
 private Date birthday;
.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find [here a Generic DAO](http://perfectjpattern.sourceforge.net/dp-genericdao.html) a working and improved implementation of that very article. Just checkout the [Example.java](http://perfectjpattern.sourceforge.net/xref/org/perfectjpattern/jee/integration/dao/spring/Example.html) at the bottom of the page. In this example you can see how you can define "slightly different interfaces between DAO for different DAO
implementations".